# Web essentials gone in vs2015 update 2

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-essentials

I recently installed vs2015 update 2.
I noticed that there's no web essentials tab anymore in the header and stuff like emmet isn't working anymore either.

Has anyone else noticed this? I can't seem to find web essentials for vs2015.2 just for vs2015.1.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the components of Web Essentials were incorporated in to Visual Studio 2015. There is a really good video on Microsoft's Channel 9 featuring Web Essentials Developer Mads Kristensen who explains what has moved from Web Essentials in to the Visual Studio 2015 product as well as the future of Web Essentials.

[Modern Web Development Tools in Visual Studio 2015 with Mads Kristensen](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Modern-Web-Development-Tools-in-Visual-Studio-2015-with-Mads-Kristensen)

Hopefully that answers your questions about Web Essentials